# Libreoffice calc how to filter by a list of ID

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have 2 spreadsheet:
- one with 14000 raw that contains all the information, first column is the ID
- one with the first column containing ID i'm interested in

I need to get the first speedsheet filtered deleting all the raw that are not in the second

Example

spreadsheet A

```
1 | aa1 | bb1
2 | aa2 | bb2
3 | aa3 | bb3
4 | aa4 | bb4
5 | aa5 | bb5
```

spreadsheet B

```
1 |    
3 |
5 |
```

what i would like to get
spreadsheet B or A filtered

```
1 | aa1 | bb1
3 | aa3 | bb3
5 | aa5 | bb5
```

Comment: see https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP and https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_VLOOKUP_function ...

Comment: Just to expand a bit on the above comment, the VLOOKUP formulas would be placed in Spreadsheet B next to the Spreadsheet B IDs, with the formulas looking up the matching ID information from Spreadsheet A.  After the VLOOKUP formulas were all set up, a copy + paste special with 'formulas' UNchecked would get a copy of the data without the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Put in the top row of a helper column in Spreadsheet A (for example, column D if your data is in columns A to C) this formula:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2.A$1:A$3,0))
```

Change A1 to the top row of your column with the IDs.  Change the reference to Sheet2 to Spreadsheet B (I'm not clear if this is a separate workbook or a separate sheet).  Change the range `A1:A3` to include all the IDs in Spreadsheet B.  Make sure to keep the `$` in front of the row numbers so this range stays the same when you copy-paste the formula.

Using `0` as the last entry to `MATCH` tells it to look for an exact match and return an error if no exact match is found.  So the `ISERROR` function will show TRUE for a row without a match, and FALSE for a row with a match.

Copy and paste this formula down your helper column the entire length of the table.  You can select the area for paste by using the name box (to the left of the formula bar) and typing `D2:D14000` and hitting enter.

Now use a filter to keep visible only the rows with a match (the rows with FALSE in the helper column).  Select the entire table (again, using the name box since this is a large table).  From the menu bar choose Data→Filter→Standard Filter.  Choose "Field name" `Column D` (or whatever your helper column is), "Condition" `=`, and "Value" `false`.  Click OK.

This hides all the rows without a match.  To get a copy of your table where the rows are removed, highlight then entire visible table, copy it, and paste it where you want the clean copy to be.